# Clicking buildings in Google Maps SDK iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

How can I make these buildings respond to touch using the Google Map SDK? The points that define the edges of the building are clearly defined, so how can I access this data to determine if a touch has been made inside vs outside of the building.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it directly, else you can create `GMSOverlay` around the area you want an action then can use the Google MapView delegate function

```
mapView:didTapOverlay:
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid hardcoding location data. Do you know if Google supplies this information in any other way?